# Nautilus menus empty

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, menu, places

exact same issue as closed issue:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/64464/empty-nautilus-menus

I have a nautilus window open and when I go to file, edit, view, go, bookmarks, or help, there is nothing in the menus.  I'm trying to view my network and shared folders from other systems, but cannot get to it, as the "Go" menu is empty.  the left column of nautilus is showing the mounted drives and folders.  network is not listed there.  since the pull down menu "view" is empty, I cannot switch the sidebar from tree to places.  This system, while a desktop, runs as a VM server for me and I will not be able to reboot for a week or so.

Answer (score 1):

Issues like these should be filed as bugs. Since I've had related issues and have been told by others about similar issues, I've filed one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/886520. You should learn how to do this, because that's how bugs are fixed.

However, rebooting Ubuntu will not do any good since Nautilus is only run as your user in any case. Simply closing Nautilus and restarting it should fix all the issues. If it doesn't, then you can press alt+f2 and run `killall nautilus` which will restart Nautilus completely. The reason this might be necessary is that Nautilus is also used to display icons on your desktop, which means simply closing all open windows won't completely restart Nautilus. But in my experience, these problems go away if you just close the window and reopen it.

If you are able to provide reliable predictions of when this happens, please add a comment to the bug thread.